# How can I sum a input values created dynamically with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a list that I created like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(post, index) in posts" v-bind:index="index">
    <td>{{ post.rut }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.names }} {{ post.father_lastname }} {{ post.mother_lastname }}</td>
    <td>
       <input type="text" @blur="handleBlur(post.amount)" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" v-model="post.amount" placeholder="Ingresa el monto">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have a method like this one in Vuejs:

```
handleBlur(value) {
  this.total_inputs = parseInt(this.total_inputs) + parseInt(value);
},
```

The thing is that if I edit any input it adds correctly I mean:

If it was 0.. and I add a value 3 in the input it will say 3+0 = 3 etc...

The thing is that I just do not need to add because If I edit same input that it has 3 and I change to 4 it should say total = 4 but it says 3+4 = 7 and it's wrong because the 4 replaced the 3 number so I wonder how can I fix my code to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused - what is the desired behavior of the input when a user makes a change?

Comment: Why not just iterate through the posts array? You're already setting the value (post.amount) in the array so you can simply refer to this: `this.total_inputs = this.posts.reduce((i, post) => i + post.amount, 0);`

Comment: @h2ooooooo that is the answer!! if you add it I will accept it and TY!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this issue because `handleBlur` is being called every time any of the fields is being blurred. This means that when you blur the same field you're still adding the number, despite this number no longer existing.

In your code:

```
<input type="text" @blur="handleBlur(post.amount)" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" v-model="post.amount" placeholder="Ingresa el monto">
```

You already define the model (`v-model="post.amount"`) which means that Vue is changing this automatically in the `post` object as you're modifying the field.

This *also* means that you don't have to pass `post.amount` to the blur function, but can simply call `handleBlur`:

```
<input type="text" @blur="handleBlur" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" v-model="post.amount" placeholder="Ingresa el monto">
```

Then in your `handleBlur` method, you can simply iterate through your `post` array and sum up the different `post.amount` values:

```
handleBlur() {
    let totalAmount = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0, len = this.posts.length; i < len; i++) {
        const post = this.posts;
        
        totalAmount += post.amount;
    }
    
    this.total_inputs = totalAmount;
}
```

A shorter way of writing this is to simply use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like so:

```
handleBlur() {
    this.total_inputs = this.posts.reduce((totalAmount, post) => totalAmount + post.amount, 0);
}
```

Both of these pieces of code are doing the exact same thing.